# Pageviews to sessions without loop

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a bit of a challenging SQL problem: Let's say you have a table of pageviews which looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE pageviews (
  id          INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  user_id     INT(11) NOT NULL,
  timestamp   DATETIME NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

In this table, you have a very large number of records (>100 million). From this data, you want to generate another table which looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE sessions (
  id          INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  user_id     INT(11) NOT NULL,
  started_at  DATETIME NOT NULL,
  ended_at    DATETIME NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

The rule is that a session is any sequence of an arbitrary number of pageviews which **does not contain any gap larger than 30 minutes**.

Now I have managed to generate this table using a stored procedure which uses a loop to get the sessions:

```
DELIMITER |
CREATE PROCEDURE generate_sessions() 
BEGIN
  TRUNCATE sessions;

  INSERT INTO sessions
  SELECT NULL, p.user_id, p.timestamp, p.timestamp FROM pageviews p
  LEFT JOIN pageviews2 p2 ON p2.user_id = p.user_id AND p2.timestamp > p.timestamp AND p2.timestamp < DATE_ADD(p.timestamp, INTERVAL 30 MINUTE)
  WHERE p2.id IS NULL;

  REPEAT    
    UPDATE sessions s
    LEFT JOIN pageviews p ON p.user_id = s.user_id AND p.timestamp < s.started_at AND p.timestamp > DATE_SUB(s.started_at, INTERVAL 30 MINUTE)
    SET s.started_at = p.timestamp
    WHERE p.id IS NOT NULL;
  UNTIL ROW_COUNT() = 0 END REPEAT;
END |
```

Basically, what the procedure does is to first get the latest pageview of any session, insert it into the table, and then iteratively backtrack until all sessions are complete.

Needless to say, this is incredibly slow. Anybody have a better solution, preferably one that involves only one query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a hard problem in MySQL.  You really want window functions for this.

But, there is a way.  First, you need to define each session.  For this, find the gaps that are greater than half an hour between pageviews.  The following query looks backwards, so this is called `PrevSessionEnd`.

Next, because time is increasing, select the maximum of this value for all page views for a user that occur on or before a given page view.  The result should be that every page view gets a value that is constant over a session.  The first will be NULL, the second will be the maximum time stamp of the first session, and so on.

Then, group by this amount.

```
select USER_ID, MIN(timestamp) as started_at, MAX(timestamp) as ended_at
from (select pv.*,
             (select MAX(prevSessionEnd)
              from (select pv.*,
                           (select timestamp
                            from pageviews pv2
                            where pv2.useid = pv.user_id and pv2.timestamp < pv.timestamp and
                                  (pv.timestamp - pv2.timestamp) > 0.5/24
                            order by timestamp
                            limit 1
                          ) as PrevSessionEnd
                    from pageviews pv
                   ) pv2
              where pv.user_id = pv2.user_id and pv2.timestamp <= pv.timestamp
             ) as SessionGrouper
      from pageviews pv
     ) pv
group by user_id, SessionGrouper
```

This particular query has not been tested, so it might have syntax errors.

I'm leaving the final `insert` up to you.

This will, in turn, run faster if you have an index on `pageviews(user_id, timestamp)`.  The subqueries can be resolved only using this index.

Comment: Great solution. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to be faster than the loop solution (at least for my example data of 2 million pageviews). Any suggestions on how to improve performance are appreciated.

Comment: One suggestion is to build an index.  Another is to remove any extraneous columns -- for instance, if you have URLs/URIs in the table, these can take up a lot of space.  If the table structure is as you describe in the question, there is not much savings there.